# C table algorithm (accessing certain cells of a grid)

Tags: c, algorithm

So here's my problem: [image]

I have this grid of pixels, that I read one by one, each one with an RGB value. What I want to do is calculate each one in the represented color groups (so 3x3), then I want to add that up, to calculate the RGB of the group of pixels, which I then have to convert to ASCII. So basically downgrading 9 pixels to 1 and converting it to an ASCII character, then going on to the next group, but I really don't get the logic behind it, this is the code I have:

```
void izvedi1 (int visina, int sirina, FILE *in, FILE *o,
              int znak, int n, int* tab)
{
    int* tab2 = calloc(10000, sizeof(int));
    int count = 0;
    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < visina; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < sirina; j++) {
            unsigned char r = fgetc(in);
            unsigned char g = fgetc(in);
            unsigned char b = fgetc(in);
            znak = (r+g+b)/3;
            tab[count] = znak;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < visina; i+=n) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sirina; j+=n) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                    tab2[num] += tab[k];
                }
           }
           fprintf(o, "%c", assign(tab2[num]));
        }
        fprintf(o,"\n");
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(o);      
}
```

Comment: Why allocate so much memory for `tab2` but then only index it by `0` (using `tab2[num]`)? And what is meant by "converting the downgraded pixel value to ASCII"?

Comment: What problem are you having? Does the code work and you want to understand how it works? Or does it not work. Note that your first loop is incorrect: an RGB value is not created by adding the R,G,and B and then dividing by 3. If you did that, then `(255,0,0)` (Red) would be the same value as `(0,255,0)` (Green). Also, is the intent to reduce the size of the bitmap?

Comment: the problem is, this isnt finished, count++ and num++ after tables  will give a segmentation fault, no idea why. And by that i mean combining the rgb value of all 9 pixels, dividing it by the n*n area, then it having a value inbetween 0 and 255, and printing the corresponding character (the assign function will print that out)

Comment: It isnt literally getting the rgb, its more of how dark it is, we were told to do this by the professor so im doing that.

Comment: You mean you want a gray scale?

Comment: Yes the intend is to shrink it

Comment: Yeah, you find the greyscale like that, and then they gave us 9 ascii characters to represent on different gray scales

Comment: im still trying to figure out why the count++ gives a segmentation fault, any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't declare enough memory for `tab`. We can't see that, and in the case of `num` you only guessed what size `tab2` should be... and it depends on where you put `num++`. If it's immediately after `tab2[num...` that's a lot of memory required.

Comment: tab and tab2 are both the same size, 10000, both declared in exactly the same way

Comment: Their size should not be hard coded. It should be derived from `visina` and `sirina` which I presume to be width and depth.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the increasing problem, however i still dont know how to properly move along the table and get the values right

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Do you want to make, for example, an image that's 27 x 27 pixels into an image that's 9 x 9 pixels by taking every third pixel and averaging it with its immediate neighbors? Does the `assign` function give you an ASCII character based on the calculated pixel value?